# A "Steps" table with parent_id

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm making a table which has "steps", The thing is

> Some steps may have multiple steps involved. So while looping over the steps I should be able to show this.

### What I'm thinking of

```
+----+----------+-------------+-------+----------------+
| id | guide_id | description | order | parent_step_id |
+----+----------+-------------+-------+----------------+
|  1 |        1 | Step 1      |     1 | null           |
|  2 |        1 | Step 2      |     2 | null           |
|  3 |        1 | Step 2.1    |     3 | 2              |
|  4 |        1 | Step 2.2    |     4 | 2              |
+----+----------+-------------+-------+----------------+
```

This seems like the only logical way of doing this? But i'm hoping i'm wrong.

- Should I create another table?

Looking forward to your responses.
Thank you!

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Thank you @McNets, I guess the first approach is fine for simple 2-level situations?

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is not really my usual dbms, but looking at your sample I would suggest you another schema by adding [chapter], and use it like a [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) field of MS Sql.

```
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+
| id | guide_id | description | chapter   |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+
|  1 |        1 | Step 1      | /1        |
|  2 |        1 | Step 2      | /1/2      |
|  3 |        1 | Step 2.1    | /1/2/1    |
|  4 |        1 | Step 2.2    | /1/2/2    |
+----+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

Then indexing by guide_id + chapter you can fetch the whole tree, or you can get one chapter using:

```
WHERE chapter LIKE '/1/2%' ORDER BY chapter
```